# "lashing belt of rage"

Tags: meaning

please tell me about the meaning of this sentence:

> How satisfying it might be, momentarily, to have a direct receptacle for some lashing belt of her rage.

Answer (score 2):

[**Belt**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belt_(clothing)) is the strip of leather or other material circling the hips and holding a pair of trousers up.

[**Lashing**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flagellation) is the act of beating the human body with special implements such as a whip, or a belt.

Many abusive people throughout history have literally lashed their children/partner/subordinates with belts, although in this case it is used metaphorically.  The author is comparing her emotional rage to a lashing belt despite the fact they lack any physical target for such violence.